# How to pass variable from app_controller to layout

Tags: cakephp, layout, cakephp-1.3

I'm new to CakePhp and I'm trying to pass a variable from my app_controller.php to my default.ctp .

I tried this in my app_controller.php:

```
function beforeFilter(){
$this->set('my_var', $my_var_to_pass);
}
```

But when I do this in my default.ctp:

```
echo $my_var;
```

I got this:

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: my_var [APP\views\layouts\default.ctp, line 72]
```

I'm using Cake 1.3 !

Some ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the only thing that i can think of is that you are not using 1.3 as you say, and infact 1.2 as that did have code that converted some_var into someVar so either try

```
$this->set('myvar', $my_var_to_pass); 
echo $myvar 
// or 
$this->set('my_var', $my_var_to_pass); 
// and 
echo $myVar
```

Comment: I'm using 1.3 (maybe new but not so noob :) )!

Comment: did you at least try what i said?

Comment: try pr($this->viewVars); and see what is contained there, also if that is not working maybe one of your views is using unset() on the variable. views are rendered before the layout so this is possible

Comment: Done... myvar is not listed :( and myvar is not used anywhere else in my whole project so I can't have any unset() on it...

Comment: what is the actual name of the variable you are trying to set, or the actual code for that matter.

Comment: tried with " $this->set('myvar', 'test'); " and " $this->set('myvar_for_layout', 'test'); "

Comment: I'm setting the variable in app_controller.php, does it matter?

Comment: you know what, if you do it in beforeFilter() you need to call parent::beforeFilter() in the controller that is running if you are using beforeFilter() there also, see the final note http://book.cakephp.org/view/829/The-App-Controller

Comment: It works but I've got a call to $this->Controller->Session->read() in my appController beforeFilter()... and calling parent::beforeFilter() throw this: Notice (8): Undefined property: PartiesController::$Session [CORE\plugins\facebook\controllers\components\connect.php, line 134] (facebook plugin calls the session->read() )

Comment: that is a different issue, you are not loading the session component obviously or some other mistake you have. you are using the fb plugin from webtechnick i take it, and that works fine.

Comment: yes this plugin is great! I'm just trying to show the facebook logout button if if the user is facebook logged with my app and the standard logout button if standardly logged into my app...

Answer (score 2):

A good way to pass vars from `app__controller` to any layout, is to use the function `beforeFilter()` in`app_controller`.

This is the same function that Auth uses:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->set('your_var', 'Data for the var');}
```

Answer (score 1):

SQuat, which version of CakePHP are you using?  As dogmatic69 pointed out, there is a difference in behavior from 1.2 to 1.3.  You can get a list of all the variables available to your view with debug($this->viewVars).

In 1.2, the keys in viewVars were camelized()... in 1.3 that is no longer the case.

Comment: Can you see the variables you are looking for in the debug output?  If not, prepare a pastebin, and include the url in your response.

Answer (score -3):

To pass 'my_var' to your layout from your controller, you need to append '_for_layout' to the end of the variable name.  The code in your controller would look like this:

```
$this->set('my_var_for_layout', $my_var_to_pass);
```

In your layout file, you could access your variable passed from the controller like this:

```
echo $my_var_for_layout;
```

Comment: Doesn't work: Notice (8): Undefined variable: var_for_layout [APP\views\layouts\default.ctp, line 72]

Comment: Are you using 'my_var_for_layout' rather than 'var_for_layout'?  Make sure you're using the same name between the controller and the layout.  Also, is $my_var_to_pass assigned to a value?

Comment: $this->set('var_for_layout', 'test'); with echo $var_for_layout; doesn't work.

Comment: I'm trying to pass the variable from the app_controller to default.ctp if this can help... (with cake 1.3)

Comment: adding _for_layout does not do anything to the variable